# HTTP Header "Persistent-Auth" not consistent for different users

Tags: http-headers, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008

We have an ASP.Net 4.0 app running on IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008. Our users are all running Windows XP or Windows 7 in a domain context.

Users are authenticated using Windows Authentication.

We have two servers which seem to be configured the same. `system.webServer/security.authentication/windowsAuthentication`:

```
authPersistNonNTLM = False
authPersistSingleRequest = False
enabled = True
```

`system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication`:

```
enabled = False
```

The Beta server appears to consistently return **`Persistent-Auth: true`** for all users, whereas the Production server seems to consistently return `false` for certain users. There are two developers whose PCs were built at the same time, using the same OS image, with their ActiveDirectory profiles both modelled on mine: **one always gets `false`, the other always `true`.**

This is problem because some users  generate an `Authenticate`: header  10k long (mine is about 3k). Depending on which parts of the app have been used, you may not be able to fit a 10k Auth header and all potential session-cookies within the 16k limit.

**What settings might cause the Persistent-Auth header to vary on a per-user basis?**

Comment: We have a similar problem: two identical sites (aside from the hostname binding, of course) on a single web server. One always seems to require the user to renegotiate with each request, while the other returns "Persistent-Auth: true". Any insights would be appreciated.